# ASP.NET Web API REST Service: HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an ASP.NET Web API REST Service. It has been build using standard ASP.NET Framework 4.5 and Web API 2.2 (version 5.2.3) on Visual Studio 2013 IDE.

Using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool I am trying to check the api methods but I get http error 405. Below some screenshots from Fiddler:

Headers tab information:

[image]

Raw tab information:
[image]

Basically it says:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

Below some code snippet from my ASP.NET Web API REST Service.

**WebApiConfig.cs** :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "WarehouseApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{data}"
        );
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Warehouse")]
public class WarehouseController : ApiController
{ 
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOkResponse()
    {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);            
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DumpIntoFile/{data}")]                
    public HttpResponseMessage DumpIntoFile(string data)
    {
           // Stuff here
    }
}
```

To test it using Fiddler, from the composer I do:

[image]

However If I call GetOkResponse action method from Fiddler using GET method and url: wstestDumpFile.my.domain/api/Warehouse then it works.

Comment: The error message is very clear : "The server won't accept a Post".  Not all server are the same.  Each have their own requirements.  So you can't post data to a server that will not accept the data.

Comment: try removing route attribute from the method  DumpIntoFile

Comment: @jdweng How do you know if a server accepts POST messages?

Comment: Only by the documentation or you designed the server to accept POST,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from this: `[Route("DumpIntoFile/{data}")]` to `[Route("DumpIntoFile")]`, you are passing the data as a `post` and therefore are not passing the data as a route parameter. Then you can add: `[FromBody]` to your method parameter like: `([FromBody] string data)`

Comment: If I do what you say then I get HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: @Ralph Try remove the quotes around the parameter name `data`, like so `{data: "test"}` in the request body.

Comment: From Fiddler If i put {data : "test" } in the request body it throws error http 415 as well  but If I do not specify nothing in request body (leave it empty, I mean, I do not pass any parameter it works). Why? so how to pass the parameter string from fiddler?

Comment: In the request header I was missing Content-Type: Application/json and then in the request body I can specify { data : "hello" } and then it works.Then using your solution it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Ralph Glad to help and glad it's working for you now.